# Convert Excel 2007 sheet to tab-delimited text file

Tags: excel, vba, text

I found this code for converting an Excel sheet to a text file. How can I modify it to create a tab-delimited text file? I am not a VB programmer, so it would help if you insert the code where it belongs.

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub ExportRange()
    Dim ExpRng As Range
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AllDXL.txt" For Output As #1

    Set ExpRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    FirstCol = ExpRng.Columns(1).Column
    LastCol = FirstCol + ExpRng.Columns.Count - 1
    FirstRow = ExpRng.Rows(1).Row
    LastRow = FirstRow + ExpRng.Rows.Count - 1
    For r = FirstRow To LastRow
        For c = FirstCol To LastCol
             '  data = ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
            Data = Data & " " & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
            If c = LastCol Then
                Print #1, Data
                Data = ""
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: SO isn't a free code writing service. The problem with coding by copy/paste as you're doing is that you never learn anything about the code, so you're unable to make changes when needed, but we're not your programming staff. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code in the form of a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing:

Replace:

```
Data = Data & " " & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
```

with:

```
Data = Data & vbTab & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be shortened and sped up as follows:

```
Sub ExportRange()
  Dim ExpRng As Range
  Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AllDXL.txt" For Output As #1
  Set ExpRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
  FirstCol = ExpRng.Columns(1).Column
  LastCol = FirstCol + ExpRng.Columns.Count - 1
  FirstRow = ExpRng.Rows(1).Row
  LastRow = FirstRow + ExpRng.Rows.Count - 1
  For r = FirstRow To LastRow
    Data = ""
    For c = FirstCol To LastCol
      '  data = ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
      Data = Data & vbTab & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
    Next c
    Print #1, Data
  Next r
  Close #1
End Sub
```